# Using custom-build C-API Python 3.3.5 module

Tags: python, python-3.3, cpython

I am trying to import a C-API Python module for a game (Assetto Corsa) that uses Python 3.3.5 as scripting extension.
I am using MSVC 10.0 as described [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers) for building the extension which works fine.
Importing the produced *.pyd file works in the terminal (using Python 3.3.5) and as well in the game when the script is called.
However, instantiating a class object works only in the terminal but leads to a crash when executing it in the game.

By logging all the executed statements I know that the constructor in the C-API is called correctly, so the problem must lie somewhere else.
I think that posting all the code might be too much, and as I said, it works as expected.

> Does anybody have an idea, what might be wrong?

The target platform is obviously Windows.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the problem myself, however, I am not sure what was the cause.
Removing the garbage collection flag 'Py_TPFLAGS_HAVE_GC' and the function pointer to the destructor from the 'PyTypeObject' description did the trick.
Be careful, this might lead to a memory leak! :)